# MKMapView rotation

Tags: ios, ios6, mkmapview

Apple's latest Maps application allows a user to rotate a map. How can I add this functionality to my MKMapView? I presumed it'd just be a case of setting a boolean property (similar to `zoomEnabled`), but I can't find anything relevant in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in rotation support in the `MapKit` of iOS. You could use regular view transforms (but than all street names etc. will also be rotated of course), or you use the [Google Maps SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/) or [MapBox](http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/) or something else.

The Google Maps SDK does support rotation, even 3D rotation. The SDK Download includes an example project showcasing the functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Actually MKMapView does support map rotation starting with iOS 5.0. Either you use the `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` control in your toolbar (user taps it until the map is rotating), or you set the `userTrackingMode` property to `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading`.